# Add token on php page

Tags: drupal-7, token

I need to find the user who is signed on so I can look at his tags. My plan is to write some simple php code in the page, start with the current user, find the contact and look at the tags with SQL.  I added the token filter and token insert but the token

> [current-user:uid]

is still not replaced.

I have created a basic page in Drupal Added some text and the token. I expected the token to be replaced by my uid but all I see is the token.

Comment: Welcome to SO. While asking a question you shall provide much more information such as more description of context, what you have tried already(probably relevant code snippets) and outcome. Your question is too broad. You might consider helpful reading SO documentation in this regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following module https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert. configure it with the field where you are inserting the token.

**Edit :**

You also need to download the [token_filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module.
Go to the Token UI configure page the link would be "**admin/config/content/formats**". On that page you will see different text formats viz (Filtered HTML, Full HTML, Plain Text), click on configure link in from of these options.

Example if you click on Configure for Filtered HTML you would be redirected on the following link "**admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html**". On this page under Enable filters there is an option which says "**Replace Tokens**". Check it and save the settings. Insert the token normally in any editor then check the view.

Comment: vishwa,  thanks for your assistance. I had the Token Insert module installed. I was able to add the drop down for CKedit. All it seemed to do was make it easier to put the token on the page by giving it the selections. I am still not able to have the tokens convert the the value when you bring up the page on the screen.

Comment: If you can handle it with code you can use the token_replace() function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x

Comment: You sure did, admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html did the trick.  Thanks for your assistance